# WPF RadioButton Command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button, command

I currently have an `ObservableCollection` of custom objects which is in my ViewModel. This collection is bound to the `ItemsSource` property in a `ListBox` in my view, where each item in the collection is shown as a `RadioButton`.

With these radio buttons, I am trying to have them execute a relay command when the button is checked on (assuming that I should bind the `Command` property of `RadioButton` to the relay command), and I don't think this is the correct way to achieve this as this error appears:

- System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :

  - BindingExpression path error:'SelectCommand' property not found on 'object' ''CustomObject' (HashCode=37826814)'.
  - BindingExpression:Path=SelectCommand;
- DataItem='CustomObject' (HashCode=37826814);
- target element is 'RadioButton' (Name='');
- target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Is this because it is trying to look for the command within the `CustomObject`, rather than the `ViewModel` instead? How can this be fixed?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this because it is trying to look for the command within the CustomObject, rather than the ViewModel instead?

That is correct, you need to bind to the `DataContext` of an element which has the `DataContext` set as your **ViewModel**.

A good idea would be to bind to the parent `ListBox`.

```
{Binding DataContext.SelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}
```